# OrientDB create vertex type

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm working with OrientDB with Java API.
I have this warning, and I don't understand why:

> The command 'create vertex type 'Users' as subclass of 'V'' must be executed outside an active transaction: the transaction will be committed and reopen right after it. To avoid this behavior execute it outside a transaction

My Java code is:

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraphFactory(databaseUrl).getTx();
graph.createVertexType(User.CLASS_NAME);
graph.createKeyIndex(User.MAIL_KEY, Vertex.class, new Parameter<>("type", "UNIQUE"),new Parameter<>("class", User.CLASS_NAME));
graph.commit();
graph.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a transactionless connection to the database. Your first line should be:

```
OrientGraphNoTx graph = new OrientGraphFactory(databaseUrl).getNoTx();
```

The OrientGraphNoTx object supports the same methods for creating vertices, edges and types as OrientGraph. Note that the commands you issue towards this object will not be part of a transaction, and will be committed immediately (so you don't need the line where you commit. Still need to be closed though). I suggest you implement a way of creating the vertex and edge types you need during startup, so it doesn't interfere with normal operations.

Comment: That's exactly the case: I'd like to create types and indices in unit testing. So this operation is done once, at database start for the first time.
Thank you!